LSI SAS3008 does not recognize 4Kn device?
my LSI SAS3008 controller does not list the, Western Digital 18TB HC550 SAS WUH721818AL4206 4Kn disk.
The Seagate ST18000NM004J and other drives work as expected, maybe because it is a 4Kn device?
Can smb. please get me some hints...

Masking reset pin 3 with tape on the disk did not help and it seems that it is already the latest firmware.
Do you have any other ideas?
:~/Installer_P16_for_Linux/sas3flash_linux_x64_rel# ./sas3flash -listall
Avago Technologies SAS3 Flash Utility
Version 17.00.00.00 (2018.04.02) 
Copyright 2008-2018 Avago Technologies. All rights reserved.

    Adapter Selected is a Avago SAS: SAS3008(C0)

Num   Ctlr            FW Ver        NVDATA        x86-BIOS         PCI Addr
----------------------------------------------------------------------------

0  SAS3008(C0)  16.00.01.00    0e.01.00.08    08.37.00.00     00:00:10:00
1  SAS3008(C0)  16.00.01.00    0e.01.00.08    08.37.00.00     00:00:11:00


WUH721818AL4206 or 0f38314 is not listed in the docs?
Also the WUH721818AL4206 should not end with 4206....
How to Read the Ultrastar Model Number
Example: WUH721818ALxxyz
xx = Interface
E6 = 512e SATA 6Gb/s
52 = 512e SAS 12Gb/s
y = Power Disable Pin 3 status
0 = Power Disable Pin 3 support
L = Legacy Pin 3 config – No Power
Disable Support
z = Data Security Mode
0 = Instant Secure Erase
1 = SED*: Self Encrypting Drive
TCG-Enterprise and Sanitize Crypto
Scramble / Erase
4 = Base (SE)*: No Encryption.
Sanitize Overwrite only.
5 = SED-FIPS: SED w/ certification

ATA Security Feature Set comes
standard on SATA

Where do this shitty disks come from?
https://documents.westerndigital.com/content/dam/doc-library/en_us/assets/public/western-digital/product/data-center-drives/ultrastar-dc-hc500-series/data-sheet-ultrastar-dc-hc550.pdf
